# Linking errors in windows

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, fortran

I'm trying to compile a c-file, cfile.c, which calls a subroutine in a fortran file, fortfile.f, and it's necessary for me to compile it on windows.  The commands I'm using to do so are, in order:

```
icl /c /Qipo cfile.c

ifort /c /Qipo fortfile.f

icl cfile.obj fortfile.obj /Qipo
```

I use `icl` for linking because `ifort` seems to require the option `nofor_main` which is not available in windows.  But when I do these commands, I get the following error:

```
ipo: error #11023: Not all components required for linking are present on command line

ipo_5220.obj: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _pythagoras_ referenced in function _main
```

Note that pythagoras is the subroutine called in fortran.  Any ideas what's the matter?

Comment: I've figured it out.  Instead I used:  icc /c cfile.c, then ifort cfile.obj fortfile.f and it worked perfectly!  I hope this questions finds its way to someone else who has this problem and isn't so good with computers like me.

Comment: That is what it says in http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/fortran/win/bldaps_for/common/bldaps_compile_mlang.htm